# Print string with ASCII in octal notation in C

Tags: c, printf, ascii, octal

I open a file, get its contents, look for matches for a regex pattern and print the matches out one by one. Some of the matches contain octal notation eg. `\012` for newlines.

When I simply apply `printf("%s\n", match);` it gets printed out as `\012`. Is there a way to print out the respective ASCII characters instead (a newline in this case)?

Comment: You need to write the 2-3 lines of code that do that.

Comment: Why type is `match`?

Comment: Care to elaborate :S? Match is a `const char *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `match` is a string, you can use the function `strtol` in `<stdlib.h>` to convert it to an `int` by specifying base 8:

```
int num = strtol(match + 1, NULL, 8);
```

Note that I incremented the pointer to `match` by 1 since it begins with a `"\\"` which `strtol` will stop on.

Comment: Okay, I thought there would be something predefined but that'll do, thanks.